# How to make gradient less smooth - Android shape

Tags: android, transition, gradient, shapes

I have to use shape in my android app. This shape has three colors defined in gradient like that:

```
<shape
           ...

       <gradient
           android:startColor="#001aff"
           android:centerColor="#1eff00"
           android:endColor="#FF0000"
           android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

I have problem because this gradient moves over these colors very smooth but I need this colors to be more separate. Every color should be visible clearly, transition between two colors must be very small.

Any ideas how to deal with that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The real use for the gradient property will make the color transition very smooth. That is the whole point of it. You have 2 options. First is to use a drawable of what you are looking for, or the other option if this is for a background : 5 views (first is plain color, second gets a transtion with start (same color than view 1) and end (same color than view 3) colors, third is plain middle color, 4th is gradient between color of view 3 and 5, and fifth is last color.
With this, you can define yourself the size of the transition between each of the three colors.